# Do Gradle `Copy` tasks depend automatically on tasks in its `from` blocks?

Tags: gradle

Let's say there is a Gradle task that produces an artifact. For example, a Zip task:

```
tasks.register("myZip", Zip) {
    ...
}
```

Would the following task of type `Copy` *automatically* gain a dependency on task `myZip`?

```
task copyMyZips(type: Copy) {
    from { subprojects.findAll { it.tasks.findByName('myZip') }.myZip }
    into '/tmp'
}
```

Note the really convoluted way of referring to the task `myZip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The `Copy` tasks do gain dependency on task *outputs* and *tasks* which are mentioned in their `from` blocks.

Per [documentation of method `from` in class `Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:from(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) as of Gradle 7.4:

> `AbstractCopyTask from(Object sourcePath, Closure c)`
>
> Specifies the source files or directories for a copy and creates a child `CopySourceSpec`. The given source path is evaluated as per `Project.files(java.lang.Object[])`.

in turn, [documentation of `Project.files(java.lang.Object[])`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:files(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a `ConfigurableFileCollection` containing the given files. You can pass any of the following types to this method:
>
> [...most of the list snipped...]
>
> - A [`Task`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html). Converted to the task's output files. **The task is executed** if the file collection is used as an input to another task.
> - A [`TaskOutputs`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html). Converted to the output files the related task. **The task is executed** if the file collection is used as an input to another task.

Unfortunately, the documentation of `Copy` does not refer to what is passed into method `from` as "inputs". However, judging by the [code of `AbstractCopyTask.java`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v7.4.0/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.java#L81-L85) every change to the `CopySpec` of the `Copy` task is propagated to the [inputs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html#getInputs--) via a `ChildSpecListener`. The listener is added to the field `CopySpecInternal rootSpec` .